# Spring boot reactor test how to log and check test of Flux<String> with StepVerifier contains string

Tags: java, spring-webflux, project-reactor, reactor

I have a spring boot test with code that creates a simple `Flux<String` of asynchronous results. I want to test that there is a result that contains the string `price`. The code is like this:

```
@SpringBootTest
@ContextConfiguration(classes = PriceTests.class)
public class PriceTests {

@Autowired
RestController controller;

    @Test
    public void DoPriceTests() throws InterruptedException
    {
        Flux<String> prices = controller.getPrices();

        Logs.Info("Test prices");  

        StepVerifier.create(prices)
        .expectNextMatches(s -> s.contains("price"))
        .expectComplete()
        .verify(Duration.ofSeconds(3));
    }
}
```

The trouble is I have noticed that when there are no prices, the test is still passing! That should not happen. How can I `log` the `expectNextMatches` string? For example, something like this, that would show what the actual value of the `Flux<String>` of each price was:

```
StepVerifier.create(prices)
  .expectNextMatches(s -> {
      Logs.Info(s);
      s.contains("price");
  })
  .expectComplete()
  .verify(Duration.ofSeconds(3));
```

Comment: a empty flux is not an error and should not be treated as such. If you want it to fail, you need controller.getPrices() to return an error on empty.

Comment: an empty flux does not contain the string “price” as expected by the expectNextMatches test predicate ?

Comment: `StepVerifier.create(Flux.empty()).expectNextMatches(s -> s.equals("hello")).expectComplete().verify(Duration.ofSeconds(3));` This code fails as expected. Isn't it possible that something is wrong with your production code?

Answer (score 0):

Finally some answers, either to use `blockfirst` or `StepVerifier` to subscribe to the `Flux` and then use regular Hamcrest asserts on the `String` data. Giving a 3 second timeout before the test finishes.

```
import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.containsString;
// Other imports

@SpringBootTest
@ContextConfiguration(classes = PriceTests.class)
public class PriceTests {

@Autowired
RestController controller;

@Test
public void UseBlock() throws InterruptedException
{
    Flux<String> prices = controller.getPrices();

    Logs.Info("Test prices");  

    // Using block
    String myPrice = prices.blockFirst(Duration.ofSeconds(3));        
    Logs.Info(myPrice);
    assertThat(myPrice, containsString("price"));
}

@Test
public void UseStepVerifier() throws InterruptedException
{
    Flux<String> prices = controller.getPrices();

    Logs.Info("Test prices");  

    // Using StepVerifier
    StepVerifier.create(prices)
        .assertNext(s -> 
        {
            Logs.Info(s);
            assertThat(s, containsString("price"));
        })
        .thenCancel()
        .verify(Duration.ofSeconds(3));
}
```